# Primary decomposition of $ (x,y^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $K[x,y]$ is a ring. How can I find primary decomposition of $(x,y^2)$ ideal? Thanks

Comment: You could use Macaulay 2. :)

Comment: Isn't that ideal already primary?

Comment: @Joanpemo That's what Macaulay2 said.

Comment: @Jake Thank you. I don't have idea what or who Macaulay2 is.

Comment: @Joanpemo It's a very nice computer algebra system. You should check it out.

Comment: @Jake Thank you very much. Is that available on line somewhere, or do you have to purchase it?

Comment: @Joanpemo It is available here  for free ( http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/ ) . There is also a very nice feature in the link to try it out without downloading it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jake, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that, given an ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ in a commutative ring $R$, if the radical $\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}}$ is maximal, then $\mathfrak q$ is primary.

In you case, note that $(x,y^2)=(x)+(y^2)$
$$\sqrt{(x)+(y^2)}=\sqrt{\sqrt{(x)}+\sqrt{(y^2)}}=\sqrt{(x)+(y)}$$
and since $K[x,y]/(x,y)\simeq K$ is a field, you're done.

No need to use computer algebra in these cases, you'll get lazy as me :)

Comment: Nice answer! +1